# Cloud function deployment issue

Tags: function, go, cloud

When I deploy cloud function I get the following error.

I am using go mod and I am able to build and run all the integration test from my sandbox,

One of the cloud function dependency uses private github repo,

When I deploy cloud function
go: github.com/myrepo/ptrie@v0.1.: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /builder/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/41e03711c0ecff6d0de8588fa6de21a2c351c59fd4b0a1b685eaaa5868c5892e: exit status 128:
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: This question was discussed many times, please look at this[1] thread, some users stated they found a workaround[2] when using Go modules.


  [1]: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26145
  [2]: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27254

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a personal access token within Github and then configure git to use that token.

That command would look like this:

```
git config --global url."https://{YOUR TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

After that, git should be able to read from your private repo

Answer (score 0):

How about using endly to automate your cloud function build, in this case you would 
use go mod with vendor, where you private repo would be added to vendor folder, 
Make sure that you add .gcloudignore to not incliude go.mod, go.sum

@.gcloudignore

```
go.mod
go.sum
```

The automation workflow with endly that uses private repo with credentials may look like the following

@deploy.yaml

```
init:
  appPath: $WorkingDirectory(.)
  target:
    URL: ssh://127.0.0.1/
    credentials: localhost
  myGitSecret: ${secrets.private-git}
pipeline:
  secretInfo:
    action: print
    comments: print git credentials (debuging only_
    message: $AsJSON($myGitSecret)

  package:
    action: exec:run
    comments: vendor build for deployment speedup
    target: $target
    checkError: true
    terminators:
      - Password
      - Username
    secrets:
      #secret var alias:  secret file i.e ~/.secret/private-git.json
      gitSecrets: private-git
    commands:
      - export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
      - export GO111MODULE=on
      - unset GOPATH
      - cd ${appPath}/
      - go mod vendor
      - '${cmd[3].stdout}:/Username/? $gitSecrets.Username'
      - '${output}:/Password/? $gitSecrets.Password'

  deploy:
    action: gcp/cloudfunctions:deploy
    '@name': MyFn
    timeout: 540s
    availableMemoryMb: 2048
    entryPoint: MyFn
    runtime: go111
    eventTrigger:
      eventType: google.storage.object.finalize
      resource: projects/_/buckets/${matcherConfig.Bucket}
    source:
      URL: ${appPath}/
```

Finally check out [cloud function](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e/tree/master/cloud_function) e2e testing and deployment automation